# How to hide overflow on word in background

Tags: scroll, background, overflow, hidden, cpu-word

i want to add a Word on the background but i dont want to have scrolls bars, I just want to hide the overflow word (my word is bigger than the background)

So i tried to position hit to overflow:hidden, but it doesn't work. Same with position fixed and overflow hidden.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps, if you show your code, we may understand what you are talking about. What's "background"? Is that some kind of app I never heard of? Which code language, if any, are you trying to use? Whatever it is, it should be mentioned in the tags. Speaking of tags, am I right to assume that "word" refers to MS Word?

Answer (score 0):

sorry i'm not english

I just want to hide the overflow of a word that i writte on the background of my page, without any scrollbar on the right or bottom.

And a want to do the same thing with an image on the background

So there is a picture that represente what i mean

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ish2U.jpg)